# Replacing data frame cell value where column and row name is the same

Tags: r

I'm interested in finding a way to replace cells in an R data frame that have the same column and row name. This is because I'm comparing the minimum distance between spatial objects and it is not useful to compare objects to themselves. For example, where both column name is "3" and row name is "3", the current value should be replaced with "NA".

I've been playing around with if statements but think there must be a simpler way to do this that I'm overlooking. I'm relatively new to coding so would appreciate sample code and an explanation.

Comment: Presumably, those instances where the distance is zero happens to be where row names equal column names. Can you replace the zeroes with NA so as to not get included in your min() function?

Comment: Is it just the diagonal? `diag(df) <- NA` ?

Comment: Would something like `df <- data.frame(matrix(1:12, nrow=4, dimnames=list(paste0("V",1:4), paste0("V",1:3))))` be representative of your data?

Comment: This is much easier if your data is in`{row,column,value}` notation - then you can just do `DT[DT$i == DT$j] <- NA`

Answer (score 2):

Using @SimonJackson's data:

```
d[cbind(seq_len(nrow(d)), match(rownames(d),colnames(d)))] <- NA
```

Simply `match` the `rownames` to the `colnames` and then replace using a matrix index.

If the rownames and colnames are in the same order in a square matrix/data.frame, then just:

```
diag(d) <- NA
```

...will do it.

Comment: Great use of matrix indexing! One minor suggestion, change `1:nrow(d)` to `seq_len(nrow(d))`. This makes it more robust eg for empty data frames like  `d <- data.frame()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a custom function, `replace_matching()` to do the job. It will even let you adjust what to insert in the cells:

Here's some toy data...

```
d <- data.frame(a = 1:10)
for (i in 2:10) {
  d[[letters[i]]] <- 1:10
}
rownames(d) <- letters[10:1]
d
#>    a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
#> j  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
#> i  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
#> h  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3
#> g  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4
#> f  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5
#> e  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6
#> d  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7
#> c  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8
#> b  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9
#> a 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

The function...

```
replace_matching <- function(df, replace_with = NA) {
  # Find all combinations of row and column names
  name_grid <- expand.grid(rownames(df), colnames(df), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  # Find any names with matches
  matched_names <- name_grid$Var1[name_grid$Var1 == name_grid$Var2]

  # Wherever there are matches, set cell to NA
  for (mn in matched_names) {
    df[mn, mn] <- replace_with
  }

  return(df)
}
```

Default use case...

```
replace_matching(d)
#>    a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
#> j  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 NA
#> i  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2 NA  2
#> h  3  3  3  3  3  3  3 NA  3  3
#> g  4  4  4  4  4  4 NA  4  4  4
#> f  5  5  5  5  5 NA  5  5  5  5
#> e  6  6  6  6 NA  6  6  6  6  6
#> d  7  7  7 NA  7  7  7  7  7  7
#> c  8  8 NA  8  8  8  8  8  8  8
#> b  9 NA  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9
#> a NA 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

Changing default replacement value to -99...

```
replace_matching(d, -99)
#>     a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j
#> j   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 -99
#> i   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2 -99   2
#> h   3   3   3   3   3   3   3 -99   3   3
#> g   4   4   4   4   4   4 -99   4   4   4
#> f   5   5   5   5   5 -99   5   5   5   5
#> e   6   6   6   6 -99   6   6   6   6   6
#> d   7   7   7 -99   7   7   7   7   7   7
#> c   8   8 -99   8   8   8   8   8   8   8
#> b   9 -99   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9
#> a -99  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10
```